# Copy another vector for a smaller size

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17

I have 2 vectors. I want the second vector to copy the first vector for the size of **n** which is less than the length of the first vector. (the second vector length should be n too)

I tried doing this by a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    //secVector[i] will equal firstVector[i] and n is less than fristVector length
}
```

but the time complexity of this is O(n) and it takes a lot of time in large lengths, I wonder if there is any function could do this faster.

Comment: To copy `n` elements you have to read and write `n` elements.  Copy can never be done in less than O(n).  If you wish to improve performance ask yourself if you need the copy in the first place or can you just hold begin and end references into the original vector?

Comment: Copy operation cannot be efficient more than O(n).

Comment: Also see [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n).

Comment: perhaps [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with std vector.

There are immutable vectors where this can be done in logarithmic time, such as https://sinusoid.es/immer/ - this uses wide B trees and copy on write to give near-vector performance with O(1) copy and O(lg n) slice.

Such structures are considered exotic.